# Python 3: Can I run a subprocess and obtain its output, without it knowing that it is being piped?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pipe, io-redirection

I am writing a program that calls `ls` like this:

```py
import subprocess as sp
sp.run(['ls', '--color=auto'], stdout=sp.PIPE)
```

The problem is that `ls` detects that its output is being piped, so it does not decorate its output with colors. But I would like to somehow trick the command to think that it is outputting to a tty, thus displaying colors. The reason I need to capture the output is because I want to process the output additionally before displaying it to the user.

I tried to redirect `sys.stdout`to a `StringIO` object and then call `sp.run` without piping, but it doesn't work:

```py
import sys, subprocess as sp
from io import StringIO
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with StringIO() as buf, redirect_stdout(buf):
    sp.run(['ls', '--color=auto'])
    output = buf.getvalue()

processed_output = process_in_some_way(output)
print(processed_output)
```

Here, the `sp.run` command outputs to stdout and `output` is empty, which means that the redirection did not work.

**Note:** Due to some practical constraints, I cannot just replace `--color=auto` with `--color=always`.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. The right question is not "how can I not use `sp.PIPE`?", but, "how can I prevent `ls` from detecting that its output is going to a pipeline?"

Comment: What "practical constraints"?

Comment: @chepner The thing is that I want the user to be able to make custom aliases for this command. And the user could define an alias lss='ls --color=auto'. In this case I would want the output to be colored if my program (call it cmd.py) was executed as 'cmd.py lss' but uncolored if executed as 'cmd.py lss | another_command'. Anyway, I just wanted to eliminate that obvious easy answer that I feel is not generalizable enough for what I want to do.

Comment: Even if you use `shell=True`, the user's alias won't be defined in the shell that `subprocess` uses to start the command.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Yes, you are right. Thank you.

Comment: @chepner I would parse the alias myself, not using a shell. The user would define the alias in a config file.

Comment: Then, for example, I would make it the user's responsibility to use `--color=always` in their alias definition.

Comment: @chepner But then the output will always be colored even if my command cmd.py is being piped to something. Sure I can parse the alias and detect if it contains --color=... and act accordingly. But what if it is aliased to lsd (a more modern alternative to ls)? This command supports icons too. So I would have to hardcode something that checks if the user's alias contains '--icon=...'. This approach is not very general.

Comment: @HarisGušić, sounds like you want to prepend `unbuffer` only if `os.isatty(1)` is True

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I was thinking exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a 3rd-party utility here that acts as a terminal (from the perspective of the program being run), so it sees that it has a TTY, then emits the output written to that terminal to regular stdout.

A widely available, easy-to-use tool for the job (included in the `expect` suite) is `unbuffer`. Thus:

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.run(['unbuffer', 'ls', '--color=auto'], stdout=sp.PIPE)
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I would much prefer if I could accomplish this using python only, but it is not a dealbreaker. I will wait a little more before accepting your answer in case I get other answers. Cheers!

Comment: It's certainly possible to do this in pure Python. See the PTY handling logic in https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/pexpect/pty_spawn.py, and particularly the `ptyprocess` library it uses, at https://github.com/pexpect/ptyprocess