# How to get all output from subprocess.PIPE

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, stdout

I am wrapping a GUI tool around a command line tool in python and I am using subprocess module.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    args, stdout=subprocess.PIP, encoding='utf8',
)

while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if output == b"" and process.poll() is not None:
        print("BREAKING")
        break
    if output:
        print(f'stdout: {output.strip()}')
result_code = process.poll()
print(f"result_code: {result_code }")
```

I am trying to read all output from the console, but with `subprocess.PIPE` I can only read part of it.

Below is output from wrapper script using subprocess:

[image: Output using subprocess]

Below is output I want to read:

[image: Output fom using command line tool directly]

Using the `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, it does not include the `Download 9%, Download 12%` etc.

How can I also capture this sys output?

I've tried using `stdout=sys.stdout`, this will output evertything but I can't read from it like `process.stdout.readline()` to handle the output.

Comment: In your Terminal, try sending `stdout` and `stderr` to different places so you can see what is directed where and what you need to capture. `./someCommand > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt`

Comment: You may also get less information printed when stderr doesn't go direct to a terminal as a deliberate implementation decision in the program you're running, but stderr would be my first bet; it's supposed to be used for all diagnostic logs and everything else that isn't output as such. Status information is certainly diagnostic in nature, so stderr is not just errors.

Comment: Anyhow, if the data isn't on stderr either, it's the program you're wrapping, not Python, that makes this decision. Look at its implementation and docs.

Comment: (can you trick it into thinking its output goes to a TTY? Yes, and we have existing Q&A describing how to do that, but look for a configuration flag first; if it's open source, maybe patch it to add such a flag).

Comment: If that's the route you need to go, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67533909/python-3-can-i-run-a-subprocess-and-obtain-its-output-without-it-knowing-that. If capturing stderr is enough, then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72918072/how-to-capture-both-stdout-and-stderr-at-the-same-using-subprocess-popen